# Require minimum number of entries along dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function `fct` that does something with 3 dimensional coordinate points:

```
def fct(p):
  # does something with p

points = np.array((n_points, 3))
fct(points)
```

Now, it could also happen that points are 2 dimensional. Nevertheless, the function should be able to take them and use them as if they were 3 dimensional with the z-axis equal to zero.

Currently, I do it as follows:

```
def fct(p):
  p3 = np.zeros((p.shape[0], 3))
  p3[:, 0 : p.shape[1]] = p # accepts 2 or 3 dims in p
  # does something with p3

points = np.array((n_points, 2))
fct(points)
```

So that requires a copy. **Is there a built in, more efficient way?**

Comment: So, which part specifically do you think is not efficient enough?

Comment: Without knowing something about the `does something` we can't say whether this copy is (relatively) expensive or not.